# vb.net pdf not showing in search page

Tags: vb.net

This is what I've tried but vb.net pdf not showing in search page;

```
Private Sub btnenter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnenter.Click

        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=AchevePC2;Initial Catalog=hrms;Integrated Security=True")
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [application] WHERE 1 = 1"
            If txtappfrom.Text <> "" AndAlso txtappto.Text <> "" Then
                query += " AND applicationid BETWEEN '" + txtappfrom.Text + "' AND '" + txtappto.Text + "'"
            ElseIf txtappfrom.Text <> "" Then
                query += " AND applicationid = '" + txtappfrom.Text + "'"
            End If
            If dtpfrom.Text <> "" AndAlso dtpto.Text <> "" Then
                query += " AND interviewdtp BETWEEN '" + dtpfrom.Text + "' AND '" + dtpto.Text + "'"
            ElseIf dtpto.Text <> "" Then
                query += " AND interviewdtp = '" + dtpto.Text + "'"
            End If
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            adp.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ' Assuming you have a DataGridView named dgvApplications on ap06 form
                ap06.agv.DataSource = dt
                ap06.Show()
                apadd.Text = ""
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("No records found.", "No Records", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I am new in vb.net but successfully inserted the data but now want to select search the binary pdf data it's not visible it's showing error.

Comment: What error? You need to provide all the relevant information. Explain exactly what you expect to happen and exactly what does happen. You should not expect us to work out what you're trying to do from code that doesn't do it.

Comment: Don't insert values into SQL code using concatenation like that. There's every chance that that is the source of your issue but, as you haven't explained what happens and what data is in use when it happens, we can only guess. ALWAYS use parameters to insert values into SQL code. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my take on the subject. Fix that first and then come back if you still have a problem, otherwise delete the question.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about converting C# code to VB.NET so I have removed that irrelevant tag. Don't add irrelevant tags and do add all tags that are relevant, e.g. if the issue is a syntax error in your SQL code then the tags should reflect that.